# Unable to create a new object in a web service constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, constructor

**Question background:**

I have a web service that consumes a standard class library C# project. This allows the web methods to access the class library's methods.

**Issue:**

Currently, when I try and create the class in the web services constructor, it is **always** null.

The code:

```
public class ControlService
{
    private IInterface _ControlFacade;

    //*****Default empty constructor
    public ControlService()
    {

    } 

    //*****ERROR!ControlFacade is always null.*****
    public ControlService(string uriServerPath)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(uriServerPath))
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Server path must be specified");
        }
            _ControlFacade = new ControlFacade(uriServerPath);
    } 

    [WebMethod]
    public void UseMethod()
    {
       //Access method i.e _ControlFacade.Method1();
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can tell me why this is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework creates `ControlService` by calling parameterless constructor. This is why `_ControlFacade` class field stays `null`. Who do you expect will be calling the constructor with `string` parameter?

Comment: I want the web service to create and then consume the _ControlService object as this has the methods I want to return when the Control Service methods are called. I will always be supplying a string Uri value so I would expect the object in this constructor to be created?

Comment: again - what code calls `new ControlService(uriServerPath)`?

Comment: you got me in the right direction here. I wasn't actually supplying a string to the calling code, so It was never going to hit that constructor.